# Show the first result in an each loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So i have this loop at the moment in rails

```
<% @gresults.each do |gr| %>
```

How would i go about getting just the first response of this?

I'm just trying to use this elsewhere, there is an option that it would be the only one there.

Thanks

Comment: If the requirement is to display only one result, then why don't you find only one result and display it? For example, `@gresults.first`

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have the following loop in your code:

```
<% @gresults.each do |gr| %>
    <h1><%= gr.name %></h1>
    <p><%= gr.description %></p>
<% end %>
```

...or anything similar where you're performing a series of actions on each "gresult." The following code would do exactly what you asked:

```
<h1><%= @gresults.first.name %></h1>
<p><%= @gresults.first.description %></p>
```

However, this begs a question; are you doing *anything* with the other gresults in the `@gresults` array? If not, then you should not be gathering the entire results. Imagine that your controller currently looks like this:

```
def index
    @gresults = GResult.all
end
```

If you instead changed it to this code you would not be wasting the resources passing all of the gresults around, and would instead only need to handle the first (the one you're trying to display):

```
def index
    @gresult = GResult.first
end
```

Then your view would look like this:

```
<h1><%= @gresult.name %></h1>
<p><%= @gresult.description %></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
<%= @gresults.first %>
```

Through `@gresults.first` you can get an active-record object.If you want to fetch a column's value then you can do this `@gresults.first.Column_name`. e.g `@gresults.first.id`

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= @gresults.first %>
```

(The `=` is needed to see it in ERB.)